# jQuery nested sortables jumpy behaviour

Tags: jquery, nested, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to allow user to drag and drop UI elements. I've 'container' and 'control', control may be in container, containers may include other containers (this is important requirement). I created simple prototype using jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
<div class="control">Control 1</div>
<div class="control">Control 2</div>
<div class="control container">
  Container drag area
  <div class="control">Subcontrol 1</div>
  <div class="control">Subcontrol 2</div>
  <div class="control">Subcontrol 3</div>
  <div class="control">Subcontrol 4</div>
  <div class="control">Subcontrol 5</div>
  <div class="control">Subcontrol 6</div>
  <div class="control">Subcontrol 7</div>
  <div class="control">Subcontrol 8</div>
  <div class="control">Subcontrol 9</div>
</div>
<div class="control">Control 3</div>
```

Then I created sortables using jQueryUI:

```
$('.one').sortable({
  items: 'div.control',
  placeholder: 'placeholder',
  forcePlaceholderSize: true
});
```

Now when I'm trying to drag "Subcontrol 8" and place it between "Subcontrol 2" and "Subcontrol 3" for example I'm getting jumpy effect, you can observe it here:

http://jsbin.com/egipu4/2

Interesting thing is - when I remove ability to drag "container" then it becomes smooth and perfect (you can see this on jsbin example below "jumpy" example, you can't drag using "Container drag area" span). I tried different "nested" plugins and techniques, google'd for a long time and the only one that worked was on this page:
(StackOverflow doesn't allow me to post more than one like, google for "Brian Swartzfager's Blog: Nested List Sort Demo" should be first, sorry!)

But it does work great only in jQuery1.2 and very old jQueryUI. If I include latest jQuery (1.3/1.4) and UI (1.7/1.8) it gets jumpy as well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case you are still interested, I recently [developed a plugin](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable) which makes nested sorting work with the latest jQuery and jQuery UI

Comment: Thanks mjsarfatti, your plugin is great and I'm already using it. There are some small issues with it which I'm fixing on fly and will post my suggested changes on your plugin's wall.